# Definition of Sonority for Flutists

Tags: terminology, sound, flute

I have not been able to find a specific explanation of what "Sonorous" or "Sonority" means for a Flutist. I have a vague understanding that it refers to sound quality. Can anyone please help me to understand this musical term better? Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? (I think it means getting a clear note without breathing/blowing sounds):  http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16540/flute-techniques-for-clear-sonorous-sound

Comment: I find Wheat's comment unhelpful. I am not familiar with how this site works yet even after reading the welcome message. I disagree with the comment of my question being a duplicate because I could not find an answer pertaining to the Flute on this subject that was simple and concise. Andy actually answered my question quickly and concisely, but only as comment rather than an answer. He also referenced a thread that did not answer my question, which is why I posted this one in the first place. I do not have enough points yet since I just found this site yesterday so a little help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sound which resonates along the entire cavity of the flute.

Comment: I don't what this could possibly mean. Any sound produced by a flute resonates along the entire cavity, including banging it with a hammer.

Comment: @EJP every pitch has a different wavelength.  Not every pitch from 0Hz-22000Hz will end up resonating ... resonantly ? ... along the length of the flute.  If you have a flute that is 700 units long, then any note that divides that 700 units evenly will resonate along the entire length.  Hammers could do this, but resonating is not just one-directional motion, but back and forth and forth and back and so on.  Does that make any more sense?